# Unknown provide $attrsProvider with ngRoute controller

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

### Angular routing not working as expected 1.6.4

Script:

```
var connect2Deploy = angular.module("connect2Deploy", ['ngRoute']);
connect2Deploy.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl: './html/loginGithub.html',
            controller: 'indexController'
        })
        .when('/apps/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: './html/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashBoardController'
        })
        .when('/apps/error', {
            templateUrl: './html/error.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/index'
        });
});

connect2Deploy.controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http, $attrs, $location) {
    let accessToken = $.cookie("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    if(accessToken !== undefined && accessToken !== null && accessToken !== ''){
        $location.path("/apps/dashboard");
    } else {
        $location.path("/index");
    }
})

connect2Deploy.controller('dashBoardController', function ($scope, $http, $attrs) {
    $scope.reposInDB = [];
    $scope.lstRepositoryData = [];
    let sfdcAccessTokenFromExternalPage;
    let sfdcUserNameFromExternalPage;
    let sfdcInstanceFromExternalPage;
    let objWindow;
    let current$index;


    window.addEventListener('message', function (objEvent) {
        if (objEvent !== undefined && objEvent !== null &&
            objEvent.data !== undefined && objEvent.data !== null &&
            objEvent.data.strDestinationId !== undefined && objEvent.data.strDestinationId !== null) {
            if (objEvent.data.strDestinationId === 'OauthPayload') {
                sfdcAccessTokenFromExternalPage = objEvent.data.sfdcAccessToken;
                sfdcUserNameFromExternalPage = objEvent.data.sfdcUserName;
                sfdcInstanceFromExternalPage = objEvent.data.sfdcInstanceURL;
                if (objWindow !== undefined && objWindow !== null) {
                    objWindow.close();
                }
                $scope.lstRepositoryData[current$index].sfdcOrg.oauthSuccess = 'true';
                iziToast.success({
                    timeout: 5000,
                    icon: 'fa fa-chrome',
                    title: 'OK',
                    message: 'SFDC connection successful.'
                });
            }

            if (objEvent.data.strDestinationId === 'OauthPayloadFailed') {
                sfdcAccessTokenFromExternalPage = '';
                sfdcUserNameFromExternalPage = '';
                sfdcInstanceFromExternalPage = '';
                if (objWindow !== undefined && objWindow !== null) {
                    objWindow.close();
                }
                $scope.lstRepositoryData[current$index].sfdcOrg.oauthSuccess = 'false';
                iziToast.error({title: 'Error', message: 'Not able to create SFDC connection.', position: 'topRight'});
            }
        }
        $scope.$apply();
        current$index = '';

    });


    $http.get("/fetchUserName").then(function (response) {
        if (response.data !== undefined && response.data !== null) {
            $scope.userName = response.data.login;
            localStorage.setItem('githubOwner', response.data.login);
            $http.get("/fetchRepositoryInDB?gitHubUser=" + response.data.login).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        let lstBranches = [];
                        $.each(response.data[i].repository.mapBranches, function (key, value) {
                            console.log(key);
                            lstBranches.push(key);
                        });
                        const sfdcOrg = {
                            orgName: '',
                            environment: '0',
                            userName: '',
                            instanceURL: '',
                            authorize: 'Authorize',
                            save: 'Save',
                            testConnection: 'Test Connection',
                            delete: 'Delete',
                            oauthSuccess: 'false',
                            oauthFailed: 'false',
                            oauthSaved: 'false',
                            disabledForm: 'false',
                            multiBranchData: [],
                            multiExtraSettings: {enableSearch: true, showCheckAll: false, showUncheckAll: false},
                            multiSelectedBranches: []
                        };
                        sfdcOrg.multiBranchData = changeListToObjectList(lstBranches);
                        sfdcOrg.multiSelectedBranches = checkIfInValid(response.data[i].repository.lstSelectedBranches) ? [] : changeListToObjectList(response.data[i].repository.lstSelectedBranches);
                        response.data[i].repository.sfdcOrg = sfdcOrg;
                        $scope.lstRepositoryData.push(response.data[i].repository);
                        $scope.reposInDB.push(response.data[i].repository.repositoryFullName);
                    }
                    $('#repoConnectedDialog').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            }, function (error) {

            });
            const avatarSpanTag = '<span class="absolute flex items-center justify-center w2 h2 z-2 ' +
                'nudge-right--4 pe-none" style="top: -15px">\n' +
                '          <img src=' + response.data.avatar_url + '>\n' +
                '        </span>';
            $(avatarSpanTag).insertAfter('#idSelectTab');
        }
    }, function (error) {

    });


    $scope.disconnectRepo = function (eachData) {
        if (eachData.repositoryId) {
            $http.delete("/deleteWebHook?repositoryName=" + eachData.repositoryName + "&repositoryId=" + eachData.repositoryId + "&repositoryOwner=" +
                eachData.owner + "&webHookId=" + eachData.webHook.id).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.status === 200 && response.data === 204) {
                    $scope.lstRepositoryData.splice($scope.lstRepositoryData.indexOf(eachData), 1);
                    $scope.reposInDB.splice($scope.reposInDB.indexOf(eachData.repositoryFullName), 1);
                    if ($scope.lstRepositoryData.length === 0) {
                        $('#repoConnectedDialog').addClass('hidden');
                    }
                    iziToast.success({
                        timeout: 5000,
                        icon: 'fa fa-chrome',
                        title: 'OK',
                        message: 'WebHook deleted successfully'
                    });
                } else {
                    iziToast.error({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: 'Not able to delete WebHook, Please retry.',
                        position: 'topRight'
                    });
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                iziToast.error({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Not able to delete WebHook, Please retry.',
                    position: 'topRight'
                });
            })
        }
    };

    $scope.fetchRepo = function () {
        if ($scope.repoName) {
            $http.get("/fetchRepository" + "?repoName=" + $scope.repoName + "&" + "repoUser=" + localStorage.getItem('githubOwner')).then(function (response) {
                $('#repoDialog').empty();
                for (let i = 0; i < response.data.items.length; i++) {
                    if (!$scope.reposInDB.includes(response.data.items[i].full_name)) {
                        const eachNewDiv = '<div class="bb b--light-silver pv2 flex-auto flex items-center">\n' +
                            '\n' +
                            '                <svg style="width: 16px; height: 16px;" data-test-target="malibu-icon" data-test-icon-name="repo-16" class="icon malibu-icon fill-near-black nudge-down--1 mr1">\n' +
                            '                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#repo-16">\n' +
                            '                        <svg id="repo-16"\n' +
                            '                             viewBox="0 0 16 16">\n' +
                            '                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 4v1h1V4H6zm0-2v1h1V2H6zM3 0c-.5 0-1 .5-1 1v12c0 .5.5 1 1 1h2v2l1.5-1.5L8 16v-2h5c.5 0 1-.5 1-1V1c0-.5-.5-1-1-1H3zm9.5 13H8v-1H5v1H3.5c-.266 0-.5-.266-.5-.5V11h10v1.5c0 .25-.234.5-.5.5zM5 10V1h8.016L13 10H5zm1-2v1h1V8H6zm0-2v1h1V6H6z">\n' +
                            '\n' +
                            '                            </path></svg>\n' +
                            '                        <title></title>\n' +
                            '                    </use>\n' +
                            '                </svg>\n' +
                            '\n' +
                            '                <span class="repoFullName" data-repoName="' + response.data.items[i].name + '" data-repoId="' + response.data.items[i].id + '" ' +
                            'data-repoUrl="' + response.data.items[i].html_url + '" data-ownerAvatarUrl="' + response.data.items[i].owner.avatar_url + '" data-ownerlogin="' + response.data.items[i].owner.login + '" ' +
                            'data-ownerHtmlUrl="' + response.data.items[i].owner.html_url + '">' + response.data.items[i].full_name + '</span>\n' +
                            '                <div class="flex-auto"></div>\n' +
                            '                <button id="ember88" class="async-button default hk-button-sm--secondary ember-view connectButton" type="button">    Connect\n' +
                            '                </button>\n' +
                            '            </div>';
                        $('#repoDialog').append(eachNewDiv);
                    }
                }
                $('#repoDialog').removeClass('hidden');

            }, function (error) {

            });
        }
    };

    $(document).on("click", ".connectButton", function () {
        const $repositoryName = $(this).closest(".b--light-silver").find('span');
        const repositoryName = $repositoryName.attr('data-repoName');
        const repositoryId = $repositoryName.attr('data-repoId');
        const repositoryURL = $repositoryName.attr('data-repoUrl');
        const repositoryOwnerAvatarUrl = $repositoryName.attr('data-ownerAvatarUrl');
        const repositoryOwnerLogin = $repositoryName.attr('data-ownerlogin');
        const ownerHtmlUrl = $repositoryName.attr('data-ownerHtmlUrl');
        const repositoryFullName = $repositoryName.text();
        const data = {
            active: true,
            repositoryName: repositoryName,
            repositoryId: repositoryId,
            repositoryURL: repositoryURL,
            repositoryOwnerAvatarUrl: repositoryOwnerAvatarUrl,
            repositoryOwnerLogin: repositoryOwnerLogin,
            repositoryFullName: repositoryFullName,
            ownerHtmlUrl: ownerHtmlUrl,
            owner: localStorage.getItem('githubOwner')
        };
        $http.post("/createWebHook", data).then(function (response) {
                $repositoryName.closest(".b--light-silver").remove();
                $scope.lstRepositoryData.push(response.data);
                let lstBranches = [];
                $.each(response.data.mapBranches, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(key);
                    lstBranches.push(key);
                });

                const sfdcOrg = {
                    orgName: '',
                    environment: '0',
                    userName: '',
                    instanceURL: '',
                    authorize: 'Authorize',
                    save: 'Save',
                    testConnection: 'Test Connection',
                    delete: 'Delete',
                    oauthSuccess: 'false',
                    oauthFailed: 'false',
                    oauthSaved: 'false',
                    disabledForm: 'false',
                    multiBranchData: [],
                    multiExtraSettings: {enableSearch: true, showCheckAll: false, showUncheckAll: false},
                    multiSelectedBranches: []
                };
                sfdcOrg.multiBranchData = changeListToObjectList(lstBranches);
                response.data.sfdcOrg = sfdcOrg;

                $scope.reposInDB.push(response.data.repositoryFullName);
                $('#repoConnectedDialog').removeClass('hidden');
                iziToast.success({
                    timeout: 5000,
                    icon: 'fa fa-chrome',
                    title: 'OK',
                    message: 'WebHook created successfully'
                });
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                iziToast.error({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Not able to create WebHook, Please retry.',
                    position: 'topRight'
                });
            }
        );

    });

    $scope.authorize = function (eachData, $index) {
        let url = '';
        if (eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName === undefined || eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName === null || eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName === ''
            || eachData.sfdcOrg.userName === undefined || eachData.sfdcOrg.userName === null || eachData.sfdcOrg.userName === '' || (eachData.sfdcOrg.environment === '2'
                && (eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL === undefined || eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL === null || eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL === ''))) {
            iziToast.warning({title: 'Caution', message: 'Please fill in required fields.', position: 'center'});
            return;
        }
        current$index = $index;
        if (eachData && eachData.sfdcOrg) {
            if (eachData.sfdcOrg.environment === '0') {
                url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.hDcPLDlm9QqJ3hRVT2290hUCTtQVZJc4K5TAQQEi0yeXFAK' +
                    'EXd0TDKa3J8.s6XrzeFsPDL_mxt&prompt=login&redirect_uri=https://forceci.herokuapp.com/sfdcAuth&state=' + eachData.sfdcOrg.environment;
            } else if (eachData.sfdcOrg.environment === '1') {
                url = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.hDcPLDlm9QqJ3hRVT2290hUCTtQVZJc4K5TAQQEi0yeXFAK' +
                    'EXd0TDKa3J8.s6XrzeFsPDL_mxt&prompt=login&redirect_uri=https://forceci.herokuapp.com/sfdcAuth&state=' + eachData.sfdcOrg.environment;
            } else {
                url = eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL + '/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.hDcPLDlm9QqJ3hRVT2290hUCTtQVZJc4K5TAQQEi0yeXFAK' +
                    'EXd0TDKa3J8.s6XrzeFsPDL_mxt&prompt=login&redirect_uri=https://forceci.herokuapp.com/sfdcAuth&state=' + eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL;
            }
            const newWindow = objWindow = window.open(url, 'ConnectWithOAuth', 'height=600,width=450,left=100,top=100');
            if (window.focus) {
                newWindow.focus();
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.createNewConnection = function ($index) {
        $.removeCookie('SFDC_ACCESS_TOKEN', {path: '/'});
        $.removeCookie('SFDC_USER_NAME', {path: '/'});
        $.removeCookie('SFDC_INSTANCE_URL', {path: '/'});
        const sfdcOrg = {
            orgName: '',
            environment: '0',
            userName: '',
            instanceURL: '',
            authorize: 'Authorize',
            save: 'Save',
            testConnection: 'Test Connection',
            delete: 'Delete',
            oauthSuccess: 'false',
            oauthFailed: 'false',
            oauthSaved: 'false',
            disabledForm: 'false',
            multiBranchData: checkIfInValid($scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcOrg.multiBranchData) ? [] : $scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcOrg.multiBranchData,
            multiExtraSettings: {enableSearch: true, showCheckAll: false, showUncheckAll: false},
            multiSelectedBranches: []
        };
        $scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcOrg = sfdcOrg;
        sfdcAccessTokenFromExternalPage = '';
        sfdcUserNameFromExternalPage = '';
        sfdcInstanceFromExternalPage = '';
        //$scope.disabledForm = 'false';
    };

    $scope.saveConnection = function (eachData, $index) {
        const lstSelectedBranch = eachData.sfdcOrg.multiSelectedBranches;
        if (eachData.sfdcConnectionDetails !== undefined && eachData.sfdcConnectionDetails !== null) {
            for (let i = 0; i < eachData.sfdcConnectionDetails.length; i++) {
                if (eachData.sfdcConnectionDetails[i].userName === eachData.sfdcOrg.userName) {
                    eachData.sfdcOrg = eachData.sfdcConnectionDetails[i];
                }
            }
        }

        const sfdcDetails = {
            id: eachData.sfdcOrg.id,
            orgName: eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName,
            environment: eachData.sfdcOrg.environment,
            userName: eachData.sfdcOrg.userName,
            instanceURL: checkIfInValid(eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL) ? sfdcInstanceFromExternalPage : eachData.sfdcOrg.instanceURL,
            authorize: eachData.sfdcOrg.authorize,
            save: eachData.sfdcOrg.save,
            testConnection: eachData.sfdcOrg.testConnection,
            delete: eachData.sfdcOrg.delete,
            oauthSuccess: 'true',
            oauthFailed: eachData.sfdcOrg.oauthFailed,
            oauthSaved: eachData.sfdcOrg.oauthSaved,
            oauthToken: checkIfInValid(eachData.sfdcOrg.oauthToken) ? sfdcAccessTokenFromExternalPage : eachData.sfdcOrg.oauthToken,
            gitRepoId: eachData.repositoryId,
            lstSelectedBranches: changeListToObjectList(lstSelectedBranch)
        };
        if (eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName === undefined || eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName === null || eachData.sfdcOrg.orgName === '' ||
            eachData.sfdcOrg.userName === undefined || eachData.sfdcOrg.userName === null || eachData.sfdcOrg.userName === '') {
            return;
        }
        $http.post("/saveSfdcConnectionDetails", sfdcDetails).then(function (response) {
                $.removeCookie('SFDC_ACCESS_TOKEN', {path: '/'});
                $.removeCookie('SFDC_USER_NAME', {path: '/'});
                $.removeCookie('SFDC_INSTANCE_URL', {path: '/'});
                $scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcConnectionDetails = [];
                const gitRepoId = response.data.gitRepoId;
                $http.get("/showSfdcConnectionDetails?gitRepoId=" + gitRepoId).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcConnectionDetails = response.data;
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
                iziToast.success({
                    timeout: 5000,
                    icon: 'fa fa-chrome',
                    title: 'OK',
                    message: 'SFDC connection created successfully'
                });
                const sfdcOrg = {
                    orgName: '',
                    environment: '0',
                    userName: '',
                    instanceURL: '',
                    authorize: 'Authorize',
                    save: 'Save',
                    testConnection: 'Test Connection',
                    delete: 'Delete',
                    oauthSuccess: 'false',
                    oauthFailed: 'false',
                    oauthSaved: 'false',
                    disabledForm: 'false',
                    multiBranchData: [],
                    multiExtraSettings: {enableSearch: true, showCheckAll: false, showUncheckAll: false},
                    multiSelectedBranches: []
                };
                sfdcOrg.multiSelectedBranches = changeListToObjectList($scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcOrg.multiSelectedBranches);
                $scope.lstRepositoryData[$index].sfdcOrg = sfdcOrg;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                iziToast.error({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'SFDC connection failed, Please retry. ' + error.data.message,
                    position: 'topRight'
                });
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.showDataOnForm = function (eachSfdcConnection, eachdata) {
        let eachdataLocal = $scope.lstRepositoryData[$scope.lstRepositoryData.indexOf(eachdata)];
        let lstBranches = [];
        $.each(eachdataLocal.mapBranches, function (key, value) {
            lstBranches.push(key);
        });
        eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg = {
            orgName: eachSfdcConnection.orgName,
            environment: eachSfdcConnection.environment,
            userName: eachSfdcConnection.userName,
            instanceURL: eachSfdcConnection.instanceURL,
            authorize: eachSfdcConnection.authorize,
            save: eachSfdcConnection.save,
            testConnection: eachSfdcConnection.testConnection,
            delete: eachSfdcConnection.delete,
            oauthSuccess: eachSfdcConnection.oauthSuccess,
            oauthFailed: eachSfdcConnection.oauthFailed,
            oauthSaved: eachSfdcConnection.oauthSaved,
            oauthToken: eachSfdcConnection.oauthToken,
            disabledForm: 'true',
            multiBranchData: changeListToObjectList(lstBranches),
            multiExtraSettings: {enableSearch: true, showCheckAll: false, showUncheckAll: false},
            multiSelectedBranches: checkIfInValid(eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches) ? [] : changeListToObjectList(eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches)
        };
        if (eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiBranchData !== undefined && eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiBranchData !== null && eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiBranchData.length > 0) {
            eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiSelectedBranches = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiBranchData.length; i++) {
                if (eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches !== undefined && eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches !== null && eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches.length > 0) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches.length; j++) {
                        if (eachSfdcConnection.lstSelectedBranches[j] === eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiBranchData[i].label) {
                            eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiSelectedBranches.push(eachdataLocal.sfdcOrg.multiBranchData[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //$scope.disabledForm = 'true';


    }

    function changeListToObjectList(lstData) {
        let lstOfObjects = [];
        if (lstData !== undefined && lstData !== null) {
            for (let i = 0; i < lstData.length; i++) {
                if ($.type(lstData[i]) === 'string') {
                    const branchData = {id: i + 1, label: lstData[i]};
                    lstOfObjects.push(branchData);
                }
                if ($.type(lstData[i]) === 'object') {
                    lstOfObjects.push(lstData[i].label);
                }
            }
        }
        return lstOfObjects;
    }

    function checkIfInValid(objData) {
        if (objData === undefined || objData === null || objData === '') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

When ever index gets called I can see URL getting changed `https://forceci.herokuapp.com/index.html#!/index` , but the controller for the same is not invoked until I add `ng-controller` on page.

HTML :

```
<body id="page-top" ng-app="connect2Deploy">

<div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>


</body>
```

It controller gets called when I write `index.xml` as

```
<body id="page-top">

<div ng-app="connect2Deploy" ng-controller="indexController">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>


</body>
```

Same happens with `dashboard` page. Any idea? 
Also I keep getting this error messages on Console :

> [Error: $injector:unpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)
>       Unknown Provider
>       Unknown provider: $attrsProvider <- $attrs <- indexController

Comment: What is `$attrs` that you are attempting to inject into your controllers? Given the error you're getting, AngularJS doesn't know what that is either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `$attrs` parameter from the controller constuction functions:

```
app.controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http, ̶$̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶, $location) {
    let accessToken = $.cookie("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    if(accessToken !== undefined && accessToken !== null && accessToken !== ''){
        $location.path("/apps/dashboard");
    } else {
        $location.path("/index");
    }
})
```

```
app.controller('dashBoardController', function ($scope, $http, ̶$̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶ ) {
    $scope.reposInDB = [];
    $scope.lstRepositoryData = [];
    //...
})
```

The `$attrs` is a [local injected by the $compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-) when it instantiates controllers. The ngRoute router does not inject `$attrs`.

Comment: I am changing my application to user routing, so that was left behind, thanks